# opencart Product page DIV

Tags: opencart

Not sure if this is where I post but I've got a lot of answers here so I thought I'd ask I'm in the throws of modifying the product page in open cart V2.0.2.0, I'm no web designer or programmer so I need all the help I can get. Here's my problem I want to add content to the left of the main product image on the product page , now I know that in modules I can create HTML content then display it on the product page through layouts but this pushes the description tabs along to the right leaving a large gap under the left hand column, what I would like is to have a div on the left that extends down to the bottom of the main image and keeps the description over to the left.

[image: how it looks with the columns added through layout]

I've tried modifying the product TPL file in various ways but to no avail. Any ideas would be gratefully received.

How I want it to look

[image: How i want it]

Regards Chris

Comment: What are you going to have there?

Comment: A small div that extends no lower than the main image with info regarding a colour chart and a link, similar to the Bespoke div on the right hand side.

Comment: Just use the HTML content module , and remove that border, and put in the image or w/e you need in there?

Comment: If i use the module it moves everything over to the right, I have added another image of how I want it to look which explains it better than I can. i know its all bootstrap and column related but these are defined with PHP which confuses the issue for me as I only have a basic understanding of bootstrap.

Comment: In this you want to edit the product.tpl file in your theme folder and then call particular code here from controller which you want.

Comment: you'll need to add some html and css from your theme otherwise it's impossible to help.  the basic idea though would be to float the left column and remove margin from main content area which pushes it over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you better understand, opencart calls templates like this

header - column left - column middle - column right - footer

What you need to do is to add that block to the middle column, then make a few template/css adjustments. If you throw it in the column left, it'll them echo the column left, which produces the result you've shown us. Assign the block to the middle or go into the template file catalog/view/theme/(yourtemplate)/product/product.tpl and hardcode that block.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your input and pointers in the right direction, I managed to sort it. I edited the Product TPL page and where the PHP calls the column class depending on what modules etc are being used I manually defined the columns added my new div and defined it col-sm-3 and the next image col-sm-5 and the right hand price etc as col-sm-4. I put the description in its own row and defined it col-sm-8 which spans it across the bottom of the new div and the image just as I wanted. Again thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, could you vote this up or mark it as the answer? I'm still limited on how much I can help others with my low score, since I just started. Thanks!